# How to count all different elements at each index of two 2d Vectors in scala?

Tags: scala, compare, 2d-vector

e.g we have two 2d Vectors:

```
Vector(Vector(A, A, A), Vector(A, A, A))
Vector(Vector(A, B, B), Vector(A, B, A))
```

The following result should be:

```
Vector(2, 1)
```

Because at index 0 both Vectors differ by 2 elements
and at index 1 both differ by 1 elements.

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer with:

```
val v1 = Vector(Vector(A, A, A), Vector(A, A, A))
val v2 = Vector(Vector(A, B, B), Vector(A, B, A))

val result = (0 until v1.size).map(x => v1(x).zip(v2(x)).count(x => x._1 != x._2))
```

result is:

```
Vector(2, 1)
```

Comment: you can shorten `(0 until v1.size)` to `v1.indices`